# How to count instances of matrices in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, count

I'm trying to count instances of matrices using the following:

```
    // setup some matrices to count instances of
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix1({{1, 2, 3},
                                           {4, 5, 6}});

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix2({{1, 2, 3},
                                           {4, 5, 6}});

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix3({{7, 8, 9},
                                           {10, 11, 12}});

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix4({{13, 14, 15},
                                           {16, 17, 18}});

    // collect matrices into a vector
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> vector_of_matrices({matrix1, matrix2, matrix3, matrix4});
    assert(4 == vector_of_matrices.size());

    // convert into a set, so that we know how many unique elements there are
    std::set<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> s(vector_of_matrices.begin(), vector_of_matrices.end());
    assert(3 == s.size());

    // store the counts, index wise
    std::vector<int> counts_;
    counts_.reserve(s.size());

    // handle to set iterator
    auto setIt = s.begin();

    // iterate over number of unique elements in vector_of_matrices
    for (int i=0; i < s.size(); i++){
        // count instances of current set setIt
        counts_[i] = std::count(vector_of_matrices.begin(), vector_of_matrices.end(), *setIt);
        // increment set
        std::advance(setIt, 1);
    }
```

This code segfaults on the line that calls `std::count`. Does anybody have a suggestion to get this code to work? The expected output would be a `std::vector<int>` containing 3 elements, a `2` and two `1`s.

Comment: `counts_[i] =` you only *reserved*  memory, but you don't have any elements in the vector. Therefore you cannot access the indices

Comment: counts_.push_back also solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the cppreference page on [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve):

> Increase the capacity of the vector to a value that's greater or equal to new_cap. If new_cap is greater than the current capacity(), new storage is allocated, otherwise the method does nothing.
>
> **reserve() does not change the size of the vector.**

(emphasis mine)

So your `counts_` vector actually has size 0, which means `count_[i] = ...` is undefined behavior.

Instead of calling reserve, you can just use the `std::vector` constructor to set an initial size:

```
std::vector<int> counts_(s.size());
```